# Injecting module into excel and run it

Tags: excel, vbscript, vba

In VBScript I'm injecting a module into excel files and then I want to run them. The injection goes fine but when I run it says it can't find it. I've put the location in the trust center so it should trust it just fine. The module has a public sub named Run as well.

```
Dim XL
Set XL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Dim book

Set book = XL.Workbooks.Open(wkpath + "\" + wkname, 0, false)
book.VBProject.VBComponents.Import "C:\MyModule.bas"
XL.Application.Run("'" + wkname + "'!Run")
```

The paths and names all work out. **Am I doing something wrong with this? What are my next debugging steps here.**

[EDIT]
Actually it looks like some references aren't being selected now so it's getting an error about user-defined type not defined, but that's not the error that I get from VBScript. I had to do what is happening manually and then I saw that error.

Comment: Do you get the same error if you do `XL.Application.Run("'" + book.name + "'!Run")`?

Comment: Also, if references are an issue in your `Run()` subroutine, then you'll probably need to switch over to Late Binding.

Answer (score 0):

So I was missing a reference but the error was pretty bogus. I figured this out by stopping my process once the excel file was open and adding in the module manually and trying to run the function. So I added the following in vbscript and it worked:

book.VBProject.References.AddFromFile "path to my xlam that has the type I use"